# OpenCL matrix multiplication

Tags: memory, opencl, matrix-multiplication

I'm a beginner in OpenCL. And I've been trying to write a matrix multiplication code. 
It works fine only it gives garbage value as the output for C array. I'm unable to fix the error. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

Here's is the host and kernel code.

```
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
#define SUCCESS 0
#define FAILURE 1

// Function to convert file name into a string
int convertToString(const char *filename, std::string &s)
{
    size_t size;
    char *str;
    std::fstream f(filename, (std::fstream::in | std::fstream::binary));

    if (f.is_open())
    {
        size_t fileSize;
        f.seekg(0, std::fstream::end);
        size = fileSize = (size_t)f.tellg();
        f.seekg(0, std::fstream::beg);
        str = new char[size + 1];
        if (!str)
        {
            f.close();
            return 0;
        }

        f.read(str, fileSize);
        f.close();
        str[size] = '\0';
        s = str;
        delete[] str;
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "Error: failed to open file\n:" << filename << endl;
    return FAILURE;
}

int main()
{
    cl_uint status;
    cl_int *error;
    int A[9] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    int B[9] = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};
    int C[9] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    // Setting up platforms
    cl_platform_id platform = NULL;
    cl_uint numPlatforms = 0;
    // Getting no of platforms
    status = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);
    if (status != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "\nUnable to query platforms";
        return 0;
    }

    // Get the platform
    if (numPlatforms > 0)
    {
            cl_platform_id*platforms=
                  cl_platform_id*)malloc(numPlatforms*sizeof(cl_platform_id));
            status = clGetPlatformIDs(numPlatforms, platforms, NULL);
            platform = platforms[0];
            free(platforms);
    }

    cl_uint numDevices = 0;
    cl_device_id *devices = NULL;
    status =
        clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 0, devices, &numDevices);

    if (numDevices == 0)
    {
        cout << "No GPU device available! Choosing CPU.\n";
        status = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 0, devices,
                                &numDevices);
        devices = (cl_device_id *)malloc(numDevices * sizeof(cl_device_id));
        status = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, numDevices,
                                devices, NULL);
    }

    else
    {
        devices = (cl_device_id *)malloc(numDevices * sizeof(cl_device_id));
        status = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, numDevices,
                                devices, NULL);
        if (status == 0)
        {
            cout << "Device error!";
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // Creating contexts

    cl_context context =
        clCreateContext(NULL, 1, devices, NULL, NULL, (cl_int *)status);

    if (status != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << status;
    }

    // Creating command queues
    cl_command_queue command =
        clCreateCommandQueue(context, devices[0], 0, NULL);
    //  if(error!=CL_SUCCESS)
    //{
    //  cout<<error;
    //}

    // Creating buffers
    cl_mem bufferA = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
                                    3 * 3 * sizeof(int), NULL, NULL);
    cl_mem bufferB = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
                                    3 * 3 * sizeof(int), NULL, NULL);
    cl_mem bufferC = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
                                    3 * 3 * sizeof(int), NULL, NULL);

    status = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command, bufferA, CL_TRUE, 0, 9 * sizeof(int),
                                  (void *)A, 0, NULL, NULL);
    status = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command, bufferB, CL_TRUE, 0, 9 * sizeof(int),
                                  (void *)B, 0, NULL, NULL);
    // status=clEnqueueReadBuffer(command,bufferA,CL_TRUE,0,9*sizeof(int),(void*)C,0,NULL,NULL);

    const char *filename = "kernel.cl";
    string sourceStr;
    status = convertToString(filename, sourceStr);
    const char *source = sourceStr.c_str();
    size_t sourceSize[] = {strlen(source)};
    cl_program program =
        clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, &source, sourceSize, NULL);

    status = clBuildProgram(program, numDevices, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    cl_kernel myKernel = clCreateKernel(program, "multiply", NULL);

    // Setting kernel arguments
    clSetKernelArg(myKernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &bufferC);
    clSetKernelArg(myKernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &bufferA);
    clSetKernelArg(myKernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &bufferB);

    size_t localws[2] = {9, 9};
    size_t globalws[2] = {3, 3};

    status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command, myKernel, 2, NULL, globalws,
                                    localws, 0, NULL, NULL);
    status = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command, bufferC, CL_TRUE, 0, 9 * sizeof(int),
                                 (void *)C, 0, NULL, NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) cout << C[i] << " ";
    status = clReleaseKernel(myKernel);  // Release kernel.
    status = clReleaseProgram(program);  // Release program object.
    status = clReleaseMemObject(bufferA);  // Release mem object.
    status = clReleaseMemObject(bufferB);
    status = clReleaseMemObject(bufferC);
    status = clReleaseCommandQueue(command);  // Release  Command queue.
    status = clReleaseContext(context);  // Release context.
}
```

Kernel code:

```
__kernel void multiply(_global int outputC, _global int inputA,
                       _global int inputB)
{
    int row = get_global_id(0);
    int col = get_global_id(1);

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        sum += inputA[row * 3 + 1] * inputB[i * 3 + col];

    outputC[row + 3 + col] = sum;
}
```

Comment: This can hardly be the right kernel code: The arguments should at least be *pointers* - that is `_global int *outputC` instead of `_global int outputC`. This kernel should not even compile, but you won't notice that: You should *definitely* check whether the "status" code returned by `status=clBuildProgram(...)` is `CL_SUCCESS` or not!

Comment: I don't know OpenCL enough but you have 3 inclusions that are wrong, they should be `<cstdlib>`, `<cassert>` and `<string>` .

Comment: Yes. It isn't. I tried a simple hello world program also. It's still not giving CL_SUCCESS. How do I debug it?

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to write this yourself and not using libraries that already contain matrix multiplication, like clMath or ArrayFire (that I work on)? Just curious if this is a learning exercise for you, or if you are just looking for good matrix multiplication options in OpenCL :-)

Comment: It's a learning exercise. I tried editing the code for a simple hello world program. Still not working. I changed the kernel code too.

Comment: I got my error. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already  pointed out by @Marco13 the kernel suffers from quite a few issues.

When running this kernel through a tool like [clcc](http://clcc.sourceforge.net/) you can see that there are a number of compilation errors to begin with:

```
> clcc matmul.cl 
"/tmp/OCLu7FyFF.cl", line 1: error: identifier "_global" is undefined
  __kernel void multiply(_global int outputC, _global int inputA,
                         ^

"/tmp/OCLu7FyFF.cl", line 1: error: invalid combination of type specifiers
  __kernel void multiply(_global int outputC, _global int inputA,
                                 ^

"/tmp/OCLu7FyFF.cl", line 1: error: identifier "_global" is undefined
  __kernel void multiply(_global int outputC, _global int inputA,
                                              ^

"/tmp/OCLu7FyFF.cl", line 1: error: invalid combination of type specifiers
  __kernel void multiply(_global int outputC, _global int inputA,
                                                      ^

"/tmp/OCLu7FyFF.cl", line 2: error: identifier "_global" is undefined
                         _global int inputB)
                         ^

"/tmp/OCLu7FyFF.cl", line 2: error: invalid combination of type specifiers
                         _global int inputB)
                                 ^

6 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/OCLu7FyFF.cl".
```

A tool like `clcc` is very useful for catching errors early on. Most vendors also have their own version of a standalone kernel compiler/checker: e.g. Intel has its [Kernel Builder](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/ioclsdk/2013/UG/Using_the_Intel_SDK_for_OpenCL_Kernel_Builder.htm), AMD's [CodeXL](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/codexl/) contains a static kernel analyzer. Another option is to retrieve kernel compilation errors right from your host code, by calling `clGetProgramBuildInfo` to retrieve the compiler output, after `clBuildProgram` returned `CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE`.

Once these compilation errors are fixed, it looks like your kernel is still not doing what you expect: as noted, the inputs and outputs should be pointers, as you will be passing buffers to the kernel. Also, the indexing of your input and output arrays is incorrect: In the for-loop `inputA[row * 3 + 1]` should be `inputA[row * 3 + i]` (`i` instead of `1`). When saving the result to `outputC`, I would expect `outputC[row * 3 + col]` (`row * 3`) instead of `row + 3`).

I haven't looked in detail at the host code, but I would at least make sure, especially when just starting out with OpenCL, to always check *every* return code and error. This will save you a lot of time and frustration.

Finally, if you want a quick jump-start to learning OpenCL with a hands-on approach, I would strongly recommend going through the open source [Hands-on OpenCL](http://handsonopencl.github.io/) training by Simon McIntosh-Smith and Tom Deakin. It doesn't take very long, is quite pragmatic and provides lots of useful insights. Optimizing matrix multiplication is one of the use cases that is shown step-by-step.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I did try building the log. Doesn't print anything :(

Comment: You are welcome. If this answered your question, could you please (if SO lets you)  mark this as the answer so it won't show up anymore as an unanswered question? Thanks!